# iOS loading local images from path

Tags: ios, image, three20

I am developing iPad app which reads data (around 5000 rows) from sqlite and displays thumbnail images. Only file name is saved in db. I am using Three20 library.

I could successfully load and display images by using `documents://`
So the user needs to copy around 15000 images (thumbnails, big image & actual images) to documents folder, using iTunes file sharing.

I am not sure if is this correct approach.
Can I read images directly from photo library or using documents is correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app cant directly access file system beyond its sandbox environment. But letting user copy the thumbnails is also bad thing to do as far as my point of view. I think we should reduce the work for the user.

1. You can download images from a remote url. (if not available[for first time] an store in Documents and reuse it).
2. If these images are predefined then you could add it to bundle when making the build, and access it from there. But it will definitely increase the build size.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was wondering if I can directly access file system.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was wondering if I can directly access file system. I can't put the images on web server as well, as the customer is not ready for that, its their private products which they want to keep on local resources. This image's thumbnails & sql data will be generated in desktop application, from there he has to copy. Thanks for suggesting other possibilities. I guess sandbox is the only & better solution.

Comment: You could do one thing. Since files are generated by a desktop application, get the resources in a zipfile and pass it to document through itunes, on the next reboot of the application, unzip the folder and put it inside the document and access the contents.